# Maquetación newsletter con tablas para outlook

Tags: html, outlook, email

estoy intentando crear un newsletter que se lea en la mayor cantidad de gestores de correo posible.

Quiero crear dos columnas, y que en cada una haya una foto, un titular, un subtitulo y debajo un botón. La cuestión es que no se como hacerlo mediante tablas (al parecer en newsletter, por problemas de compatibilidad con los divs, es lo más adecuado). Este es el código que tengo por ahora:

https://codepen.io/Viturbiko/pen/bavjaW

```css
       /* What it does: Remove spaces around the email design added by some email clients. */
        /* Beware: It can remove the padding / margin and add a background color to the compose a reply window. */
        html, body {
            margin: 0 !important;
            padding: 0 !important;
            height: 100% !important;
            width: 100% !important;
        }
        /* What it does: Stops email clients resizing small text. */
        * {
            -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
            -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
        }
        /* What it does: Forces Outlook.com to display emails full width. */
        .ExternalClass {
            width: 100%;
        }
        /* What is does: Centers email on Android 4.4 */
        div[style*="margin: 16px 0"] {
            margin: 0 !important;
        }
        /* What it does: Stops Outlook from adding extra spacing to tables. */
        table, td {
            mso-table-lspace: 0pt !important;
            mso-table-rspace: 0pt !important;
        }
        /* What it does: Fixes webkit padding issue. Fix for Yahoo mail table alignment bug. Applies table-layout to the first 2 tables then removes for anything nested deeper. */
        table {
            border-spacing: 0 !important;
            border-collapse: collapse !important;
            table-layout: fixed !important;
            margin: 0 auto !important;
        }

            table table table {
                table-layout: auto;
            }
        /* What it does: Uses a better rendering method when resizing images in IE. */
        img {
            -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;
        }
        /* What it does: Overrides styles added when Yahoo's auto-senses a link. */
        .yshortcuts a {
            border-bottom: none !important;
        }
        /* What it does: Another work-around for iOS meddling in triggered links. */
        a[x-apple-data-detectors] {
            color: inherit !important;
        }
    </style>

    <!-- Progressive Enhancements -->
    <style type="text/css">

        /* What it does: Hover styles for buttons */
        .button-td,
        .button-a {
            transition: all 100ms ease-in;
        }

            .button-td:hover,
            .button-a:hover {
                background: #71C5E8 !important;
                border-color: #71C5E8 !important;
            }

        /* Media Queries */
        @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {

            .email-container {
                width: 100% !important;
            }

            /* What it does: Forces elements to resize to the full width of their container. Useful for resizing images beyond their max-width. */
            .fluid,
            .fluid-centered {
                max-width: 100% !important;
                height: auto !important;
                margin-left: auto !important;
                margin-right: auto !important;
            }
            /* And center justify these ones. */
            .fluid-centered {
                margin-left: auto !important;
                margin-right: auto !important;
            }

            /* What it does: Forces table cells into full-width rows. */
            .stack-column,
            .stack-column-center {
                display: block !important;
                width: 100% !important;
                max-width: 100% !important;
                direction: ltr !important;
            }
            /* And center justify these ones. */
            .stack-column-center {
                text-align: center !important;
            }

            /* What it does: Generic utility class for centering. Useful for images, buttons, and nested tables. */
            .center-on-narrow {
                text-align: center !important;
                display: block !important;
                margin-left: auto !important;
                margin-right: auto !important;
                float: none !important;
            }

            table.center-on-narrow {
                display: inline-block !important;
            }
        }

        table {
        }
```

```html
<body bgcolor="#e0e0e0" width="100%" style="margin: 0;" yahoo="yahoo">
    <table bgcolor="#e0e0e0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" height="100%" width="100%" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
        <tr>
            <td>
                    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="center" bgcolor="#e0e0e0" width="600" class="email-container">
                        <tr>
                            <td style="padding: 25px 10px 20px 20px; text-align: center; font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 21px; mso-height-rule: exactly; line-height: 28px; color: #000; background-color: #e0e0e0; letter-spacing: 15px"><strong>DOS COLUMNAS</strong></td>
                        </tr>

                        <!-- DOS COLUMNAS : BEGIN -->
                        <tr>
                            <td align="center" valign="top" style="padding: 10px 10px 5px 10px; background-color: #fff;">
                                <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="stack-column-center"  valign="top">
                                            <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td style="padding: 10px; text-align: center"><img src="https://static.guim.co.uk/sys-images/Guardian/Pix/pictures/2014/4/11/1397210130748/Spring-Lamb.-Image-shot-2-011.jpg" alt="Global Exchange" width="260" height="auto" class="fluid" border="0"></td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td valign="top" style="font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 15px; mso-height-rule: exactly; line-height: 20px; color: #555555; padding: 0 10px 10px; text-align: left;" class="center-on-narrow">
                                                        <p>Compre o regale <strong>Millas</strong> y elija como disfrutarla con nuestros partners.</p>
                                                        <p>Compre o regale <strong>Millas</strong> y elija como disfrutarla con nuestros partners.</p>
                                                        <!-- Button : Begin -->
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="center" style="margin: auto">
                                                            <tr>
                                                                <td style="border-radius: 3px; background: #0072ce; text-align: center;" class="button-td">
                                                                    <a href="http://www.globalexchange.es/" target="_blank" style="background: #0072ce; border: 15px solid #0072ce; padding: 0 10px;color: #ffffff; font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 13px; line-height: 1.1; text-align: center; text-decoration: none; display: block; border-radius: 3px; font-weight: bold;" class="button-a">
                                                                        <!--[if mso]>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<![endif]-->COMPRA / REGALO<!--[if mso]>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<![endif]-->
                                                                    </a>
                                                                </td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                        </table>
                                                        <!-- Button : END --><br>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </table>
                                        </td>
                                        <td class="stack-column-center">
                                            <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td style="padding: 10px; text-align: center"><img src="https://static.guim.co.uk/sys-images/Guardian/Pix/pictures/2014/4/11/1397210130748/Spring-Lamb.-Image-shot-2-011.jpg" alt="Global Exchange" width="260" height="auto" class="fluid" border="0"></td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td style="font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 15px; mso-height-rule: exactly; line-height: 20px; color: #555555; padding: 0 10px 10px; text-align: left;" class="center-on-narrow">
                                                        <p>Compre o regale <strong>Millas</strong> y elija como disfrutarla con nuestros partners.</p>
                                                        <p>Compre o regale <strong>Millas</strong> y elija como disfrutarla con nuestros partners.</p>
                                                        <p>Compre o regale <strong>Millas</strong> y elija como disfrutarla con nuestros partners.</p>
                                                        <p>Compre o regale <strong>Millas</strong> y elija como disfrutarla con nuestros partners.</p>
                                                        <!-- Button : Begin -->
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="center" style="margin: auto">
                                                            <tr>
                                                                <td style="border-radius: 3px; background: #0072ce; text-align: center;" class="button-td">
                                                                    <a href="http://www.globalexchange.es/" target="_blank" style="background: #0072ce; border: 15px solid #0072ce; padding: 0 10px;color: #ffffff; font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 13px; line-height: 1.1; text-align: center; text-decoration: none; display: block; border-radius: 3px; font-weight: bold;" class="button-a">       <!--[if mso]>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<![endif]-->COMPRA / REGALO<!--[if mso]>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<![endif]--></a>
                                                                </td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                        </table>
                                                        <!-- Button : END --><br>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </table>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Mi intención es crear una fila con la imagen, otra con el titular, otra con el subtitulo, y otra con el botón. El problema surge cuando en alguna de las columnas el titular o el texto es más largo que el de al lado, que se descuadran, quedando el botón más arriba en un caso que en otro, etc. El caso es que quiero que siempre tengan una "altura fija", para que el titular, el subtitulo y el botón de las dos columnas estén siempre a la misma altura y alineados. He probado a darle un height al tr, pero hay varios gestores de correo que no leen bien esa propiedad, por lo que no funciona, he probado a hacer varios tr, pero sucede lo mismo...

¿Alguna idea?

Muchas gracias y un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

Podrías crear una única tabla para todo.

Ahora mismo tienes tablas dentro de tablas (o mejor dicho tablas dentro de tablas dentro de tablas), y el problema es que la altura de la celda de una tabla no siempre coincide con la altura de la celda correspondiente en la otra tabla... Pero si sólo tuvieras una tabla, entonces ambas tendrían la misma altura porque serían celdas de la misma fila.

Algo como esto:

```css
/* What it does: Remove spaces around the email design added by some email clients. */


/* Beware: It can remove the padding / margin and add a background color to the compose a reply window. */

html,
body {
  margin: 0 !important;
  padding: 0 !important;
  height: 100% !important;
  width: 100% !important;
}


/* What it does: Stops email clients resizing small text. */

* {
  -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
}


/* What it does: Forces Outlook.com to display emails full width. */

.ExternalClass {
  width: 100%;
}


/* What is does: Centers email on Android 4.4 */

div[style*="margin: 16px 0"] {
  margin: 0 !important;
}


/* What it does: Stops Outlook from adding extra spacing to tables. */

table,
td {
  mso-table-lspace: 0pt !important;
  mso-table-rspace: 0pt !important;
}


/* What it does: Fixes webkit padding issue. Fix for Yahoo mail table alignment bug. Applies table-layout to the first 2 tables then removes for anything nested deeper. */

table {
  border-spacing: 0 !important;
  border-collapse: collapse !important;
  table-layout: fixed !important;
  margin: 0 auto !important;
}

table table table {
  table-layout: auto;
}


/* What it does: Uses a better rendering method when resizing images in IE. */

img {
  -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;
}


/* What it does: Overrides styles added when Yahoo's auto-senses a link. */

.yshortcuts a {
  border-bottom: none !important;
}


/* What it does: Another work-around for iOS meddling in triggered links. */

a[x-apple-data-detectors] {
  color: inherit !important;
}

</style><!-- Progressive Enhancements --><style type="text/css">
/* What it does: Hover styles for buttons */

.button-td,
.button-a {
  transition: all 100ms ease-in;
}

.button-a:hover {
  background: #71C5E8 !important;
  border-color: #71C5E8 !important;
}


/* Media Queries */

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .email-container {
    width: 100% !important;
  }
  /* What it does: Forces elements to resize to the full width of their container. Useful for resizing images beyond their max-width. */
  .fluid,
  .fluid-centered {
    max-width: 100% !important;
    height: auto !important;
    margin-left: auto !important;
    margin-right: auto !important;
  }
  /* And center justify these ones. */
  .fluid-centered {
    margin-left: auto !important;
    margin-right: auto !important;
  }
  /* What it does: Forces table cells into full-width rows. */
  .stack-column,
  .stack-column-center {
    display: block !important;
    width: 100% !important;
    max-width: 100% !important;
    direction: ltr !important;
  }
  /* And center justify these ones. */
  .stack-column-center {
    text-align: center !important;
  }
  /* What it does: Generic utility class for centering. Useful for images, buttons, and nested tables. */
  .center-on-narrow {
    text-align: center !important;
    display: block !important;
    margin-left: auto !important;
    margin-right: auto !important;
    float: none !important;
  }
  table.center-on-narrow {
    display: inline-block !important;
  }
}

table {}
```

```html
<body bgcolor="#e0e0e0" width="100%" style="margin: 0;" yahoo="yahoo">
  <table bgcolor="#e0e0e0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" height="100%" width="100%" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="center" bgcolor="#e0e0e0" width="600" class="email-container">
          <tr>
            <td style="padding: 25px 10px 20px 20px; text-align: center; font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 21px; mso-height-rule: exactly; line-height: 28px; color: #000; background-color: #e0e0e0; letter-spacing: 15px"><strong>DOS COLUMNAS</strong></td>
          </tr>

          <!-- DOS COLUMNAS : BEGIN -->
          <tr>
            <td align="center" valign="top" style="padding: 10px 10px 5px 10px; background-color: #fff;">


              <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%">
                <tr>
                  <td class="stack-column-center" valign="top">
                    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
                      <tr>
                        <td style="padding: 10px; text-align: center"><img src="https://static.guim.co.uk/sys-images/Guardian/Pix/pictures/2014/4/11/1397210130748/Spring-Lamb.-Image-shot-2-011.jpg" alt="Global Exchange" width="260" height="auto" class="fluid" border="0"></td>
                        <td style="padding: 10px; text-align: center"><img src="https://static.guim.co.uk/sys-images/Guardian/Pix/pictures/2014/4/11/1397210130748/Spring-Lamb.-Image-shot-2-011.jpg" alt="Global Exchange" width="260" height="auto" class="fluid" border="0"></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td valign="top" style="font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 15px; mso-height-rule: exactly; line-height: 20px; color: #555555; padding: 0 10px 10px; text-align: left;" >
                          <p>Compre o regale <strong>Millas</strong> y elija como disfrutarla con nuestros partners.</p>
                          <p>Compre o regale <strong>Millas</strong> y elija como disfrutarla con nuestros partners.</p>
                          <!-- Button : Begin -->
                        </td>
                        <td style="font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 15px; mso-height-rule: exactly; line-height: 20px; color: #555555; padding: 0 10px 10px; text-align: left;">
                          <p>Compre o regale <strong>Millas</strong> y elija como disfrutarla con nuestros partners.</p>
                          <p>Compre o regale <strong>Millas</strong> y elija como disfrutarla con nuestros partners.</p>
                          <p>Compre o regale <strong>Millas</strong> y elija como disfrutarla con nuestros partners.</p>
                          <p>Compre o regale <strong>Millas</strong> y elija como disfrutarla con nuestros partners.</p>
                          <!-- Button : Begin -->
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>

                        <td style="border-radius: 3px; text-align: center;" class="button-td">
                          <a href="http://www.globalexchange.es/" target="_blank" style="background: #0072ce; border: 15px solid #0072ce; padding: 0 10px;color: #ffffff; font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 13px; line-height: 1.1; text-align: center; text-decoration: none; display: inline-block; border-radius: 3px; font-weight: bold;"
                            class="button-a">
                            <!--[if mso]>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<![endif]-->COMPRA / REGALO
                            <!--[if mso]>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<![endif]-->
                          </a>
                        </td>
                        <td style="border-radius: 3px; text-align: center;" class="button-td">
                          <a href="http://www.globalexchange.es/" target="_blank" style="background: #0072ce; border: 15px solid #0072ce; padding: 0 10px;color: #ffffff; font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 13px; line-height: 1.1; text-align: center; text-decoration: none; display: inline-block; border-radius: 3px; font-weight: bold;"
                            class="button-a">
                            <!--[if mso]>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<![endif]-->COMPRA / REGALO
                            <!--[if mso]>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<![endif]-->
                          </a>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>
                    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
                      <tr>

                      </tr>
                      <tr>

                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td>
                          <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="center" style="margin: auto">
                            <tr>

                            </tr>
                          </table>
                          <!-- Button : END --><br>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </td>
          </tr>

        </table>
</body>

</html>
```

En ese ejemplo he cambiado un poco los enlaces y la celda que los contiene para que se ajuste mejor a lo que había antes. Un problema de esta implementación es que se pierde parte de la *responsividad* que tenía.